# Shopify-nuxt transfer checkout to Shopify hosted store

Tags: nuxt.js, shopify

I have a Shopify store at shopify.mysite.com. This is a Shopify hosted store.

I also have Nuxt 2 app as my website and am using the nuxt-shopify plugin (https://nuxt-shopify-docs.vercel.app/) to create a cart on my Nuxt website.

Everything works, I can transfer contents of a checkout to shopify.mysite.com to pay for it etc. For that, I'm using the webUrl property from checkout object from shopify-nuxt.

However, if I go to shopify.mysite.com/cart/, the checkout contents from my Nuxt site are not there.

What's more, if I already have stuff in shopify.mysite.com store, I can see that in  shopify.mysite.com/cart/ so it seems they are two different checkout instances.

How do I share my checkout instance to shopify.mysite.com so I have a a ONE cart seamless experience?